# Scrolling between images with a crop transition

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I've been searching for a while and trying hands on to accomplish something similar to this.
In the [Fifa iOS app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fifa-official-app/id756904853?mt=8) there is a very fancy effect where you can scroll between screens, each has a difference image but the scrolling itself isn't moving the images move, but like the cropping line between them that is moving (parallax effect as in a few websites).

My issue is:
I attempted a similar effect, but hit 2 obstacles.
The mask image `CGImageMaskCreate` isn't fast enough to allow the proper cropping of the images.

What I tried is to load the 3 cropped images appearing on the screen, meaning creating 3 `graphicsContexts` for each of the 3 masks, masking the image for each.  Then, creating another buffer context that I add up the finished partials on (created 3 times, once after each cropped image then I start processing the next)
This makes sense that it is heavy, which it was.

The 2nd, I tried [GPUImage library](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) but it also felt very slow, and I minimized A LOT of the number of GraphicsContexts I'm using.
I'm definitely doing something terribly wrong, but I'm not sure where to start from. I can't find any sample code that can do something similar to tweak around.
I decided to blow up the existing code I was trying, so I'll start fresh (so don't ask me about the code :D )

I KNOW that `scrollViewDidScroll` can be smooth enough for something like that.

Comment: Tough for the readers that do not own/use that app. For improving your question, it might be a great idea to add a series of screenshots or an animated GIF or something that displays the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I just downloaded that app just to find out what you were talking about and I can still only guess that you are talking about the effect  visible on "Explore FIFA" when scrolling horizontally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should clip/mask the image views to a path rather than an image mask. Then, as you pan, the images don't move, but rather you just update the clip/mask for each image view. If you want to do that in Core Graphics, you can create a path with `CGContextMoveToPoint`, `CGContextAddLineToPoint`, etc., and then clip using `CGContextClip`.

If you want to do this in QuartzCore, you can use a `CAShapeLayer` as a mask to the respective image views, giving each mask for each image its own `UIBezierPath`:

```
// create path

UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];;
CGPoint point = CGPointZero;

point.x += slantOffset;
[path moveToPoint:point];

point.x += self.view.bounds.size.width;
[path addLineToPoint:point];

point.x -= slantOffset * 2.0;
point.y += self.view.bounds.size.height;
[path addLineToPoint:point];

point.x -= self.view.bounds.size.width;
[path addLineToPoint:point];

[path closePath];

// create shape layer, use the path, and specify it for the mask of the image view

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.path = [path CGPath];
self.imageView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

When you want to change the mask (for example in your pan gesture recognizer), you can just update the `path` for the `maskLayer`. Just repeat this process for all images that could be visible at any given time (e.g., it looks like this app has three images that are visible at one time).

This is more than fast enough to keep up with your gesture recognizer and/or custom transition. Here I have three image views and I have a gesture recognizer update the `UIBezierpath` for the respective mask layer of each of the three image views. Clearly, the paths for the layer masks are adjusted accordingly (left, center and right), but I suspect you get the idea:

[image]

Comment: Thnx, for your answer. I will try it shortly. But small inquiry. Can I use a scroll view instead of a pan guesture and read the offset to adjust the crop area ? Or the callback won't be frequent enough ?

Comment: yeap, that did it, just tried using it with a scrollView & performance is excellent . thanks a lot :)

Comment: Thank, Rob any chance you could post that sample project to github or something?

Comment: @McCygnus See rough demonstration at https://github.com/robertmryan/AnimateMasks.

Comment: @EhabAmer can you please post a example of your code at github with the scrollview ? I'm unable to merge "Rob" code in Scrollview.